# Mercurial Closing a Branch

Tags: mercurial

I have been using named branches both as feature branches and long lived branches. I just merged a bunch of feature branches into a long-lived branch, so I no longer need those feature branches muddling up the history graph (although I still want to keep the commit messages of course).

How do I do this?

Comment: Hm .. if you merged the feature branches to a long-living branch -- which you probably want to keep -- then why would you want to remove the branches that lead to the merged long-living branch? Such things are a natural effect of a DVCS driven workflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkout the branch (`hg co branchname`) then `hg commit --close-branch` to mark the branch "closed".

Comment: this does remove it from the list of branches, but this doesn't clean up the graph view of the repo (still lines for the branches that got removed). Suggestions?

Comment: Short of modifying the history, you can't clean up the graph view… Sorry. Do you want to modify the history?

Answer (score 4):

Branches in mercurial are permanent, which is why they're a good choice for things that live forever like "release 1.0" and "experimental".  For features you might want to consider something more transitory like bookmarks, clones, or anonymous branches.  All four options are very well described here: http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/

As @wolvever shows you can hide it from a list, but you can't get rid of it without making your repo a different repo entirely (and thus breaking all clones).